# RGBToHex with float r,g,b

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying the solutions in this thread: [RGB to Hex and Hex to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb) without luck:

```
function rgbToHex(my_color) {
             r = my_color.r;
             g = my_color.g;
             b = my_color.b;
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

When I call the above with the following:

```
my_color= {r: 51, g: 51, b: 9.180000000000003}
```

I get:

```
#333309.2e147ae
```

which doesn't seem right. Considering how my input is formatted, am I supposed to pass values in a different way?

Comment: Have you read [***this***](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/29/convert-rgb-to-hex.aspx/)?

Comment: The problem is in that you're coding floating values to ARGB format, every channel (`r`, `g` and `b`) should be an integer in the range [0, 255] for this to work

Comment: What are you expecting to get? If you only need the first 6 hex digits, you should remove the fractional part of each of the parameters before you shift bits and convert into hex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only works for integer values now, so that if there are float numbers in the color object the return is not doing its job properly.

I personal recommend using the built in function for javascript to return integer values from any given value.

The function is `parseInt()`

---

In your case the code would change from

```
function rgbToHex(my_color) {
         r = my_color.r;
         g = my_color.g;
         b = my_color.b;
         return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

to

```
function rgbToHex(my_color) {
         r = parseInt(my_color.r);
         g = parseInt(my_color.g);
         b = parseInt(my_color.b);
         return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may trim out float point values for the function to work properly.. You could use this:

```
function rgbToHex(my_color) {
             r = Math.floor(my_color.r);
             g = Math.floor(my_color.g);
             b = Math.floor(my_color.b);
    return "#" + ((1 << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b).toString(16).slice(1);
}
```